# How can I create a custom list find methd in cakephp-3?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

In my code I am reusing a list-find operation with custom keyField and valueField like this:

```
->find('list', [
     'keyField' => 'key',
     'valueField' => 'value'
])
```

I would like to define a custom list-find method that sets the keyField and valueField, so I don't have to repeat myself. Also it should be chainable with additional custom-find methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit: Simple and clear solution by calling findList inside the custom finder:**

```
public function findCustomList(Query $query, array $options)
{
     return $this->findList($query, [
         'keyField' => 'key',
         'valueField' => 'value',
     ]);
}
```

**First Answer:**

It is possible to use the formatResults-method of the query-Object to register a formatter that will format the results into the desired list:

```
public function findCustomList(Query $query, array $options)
{
    $query->formatResults(function ($results) {
        /** @var \Cake\Collection\CollectionInterface $results */
        $formatedResults = [];
        foreach ($results as $key => $result) {
            $formatedResults[$result->key] = $result->value;
        }
        return new Collection($formatedResults);
    });

    return $query;
}
```

Comment: You could possibly also override the base finder, ie the `Table::findList()` method, and change/set the options accordingly. And if you don't want to change all `list` finds for that table and go with a custom finder, you could internally call the regular list finder method instead of hooking up a custom formatter that is essentially doing the same.

Comment: @ndm : yes, I want to go with a custom finder (and I dont want to overwrite all list finds). If I would call the regular list finder internally, wouldn't I get second query-object? I already have one query object that was passed into the function as a parameter. How could I combine those?

Comment: I found a way to call the list finder internally: `$this->findList($query, [])` That way I can pass my $query-object into that call. Thus I don't have to deal with a second $query-object.

Comment: That's what I was referring to. All finders consume a query object, and usually return the very same query object.